# How to ask for an internal transfer?

Tags: internal-transfer

So here is the situation: I am currently employed in a group under which I no longer feel aligned, and would like to join a different group which matches more closely my interest. I know the manager of said group (was my manager previously), so I am trying to figure out the best approach of talking about this transfer. Should I:

- First talk to my previous manager and ask him if he has any open position in his new group and if he'd be interested in my profile. If the answer is yes, then talk to my current manager about it, otherwise don't talk about it.
- Talk to my current manager first letting him know why I'm looking for something different and why I'd be interested in this other group. And if he doesn't push back, talk to my previous manager in the new group.

I'm leaning more towards option #1, because I'm afraid by doing option #2 my current manager could shoot me down with the other group since I know he doesn't want to lose resources in his group.

What do you guys think?

Comment: Have you seen [this question](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/44839/2322)?

Comment: Most companies have well defined processes for internal applications. Research them and follow them.